# Are there algorithm for finding a minimum of a separately convex function (i.e., $f(x,y)$ convex in $x$ and $y$ but not in $(x,y)$)

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, convex

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is separatly convex function.  That is, for a fixed $y$ the mapping $x \to f(x,y)$ is convex and for a fixed $x$ the mapping $y \to f(x,y)$ is convex.

**Question:**  Are there numerical algorithms  (like gradient descent) for the optimization of separately convex functions? If, yes can we show rates of converges?

**Some observations:**
Since we have that
\begin{align}
\min_{x,y}f(x,y)= \min_x \min_y f(x,y)=  \min_y \min_x f(x,y).
\end{align}
This suggests that there might exist an alternating algorithm which first optimizes over $x$ and then over  $y$.

Comment: It is instructive to apply an alternating algorithm to the function $f(x,y)=\exp(xy)+\exp(x)+\exp(y)$ (which is strictly convex).

Comment: @whuber  why? Will it not converge?

Comment: Try it!  It can help to [examine a contour plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+plot+log%28exp%28x+y%29%2Bexp%28y%29%2Bexp%28x%29%29+for+x+%3D+-300+to+0+and+y+%3D+0+to+1%2F5).

Comment: I think there may have been some mistakes in those calculations (in a now deleted comment): it's not that simple to find the minimal analytically. E.g., given $y,$ a critical point for $x$ occurs where $0=\partial f(x,y)/\partial x=y\exp(xy)+\exp(x),$ requiring you to solve this equation for $x.$ The solutions are not given by your formulas.

Comment: @whuber yeah. I just realized it. Sorry for the mistake.   I removed it.  But  I guess I the lesson here is that, to attain the minimum we have to go along a very specific direction, right?

Comment: I think one lesson is that there are circumstances where restricting your searches to predetermined sets of directions can be a bad strategy.

Comment: @whuber  Will this problem go away if restrict our optimization to say a ball centered at zero of radius $r$?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can get even worse in that circumstance, because now you have to worry about the boundary conditions.

Comment: @whuber  Ok. Thanks. Do you know if there is a good literature on this? I would like to learn more about this and how to find minima numerically.

Comment: There is such an enormous literature that I'm sure my textbooks are out of date, so I don't want to recommend them.  Basic texts on numerical analysis, such as *Numerical Recipes,* provide a good foundation.

Comment: This is square in the area of operations research. Their SE is a bit sleepy, but there are fantastic resources on this. Trust region methods like you suggested can be (as @whuber rightfully noted) problematic. I'd take a gander at Nocedal and Wright's *Numerical Optimization* (personal fave) or Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*.

Comment: @kurtosis  Thanks what are some of the keywords that I should look for? I mean with respect to the structure of the function $f(x,y)$. Something that comes to my mind is separatly convex functions?

Comment: @Lisa That helps. Also, anything that can handle, say, the Rosenbrock function will likely be able to handle this function. I'd just read Chapters 1-3 and 5-6 of Nocedal and Wright. Even just skimming them will be informative. That should be all you need for this.

Comment: @kurtosis  Thanks a lot. I will check this out.